# Adjusting a code of a diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, arrow-curve

Here is the code I am trying to compile on my overleaf:

```
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge]
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
   \arrow[r,"c_*"]
   \arrow[dr,bend right,"\Delta"'] &
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee\Sigma X)
  \arrow[r,"(f\vee g)_*"]
  \arrow[d,shift right=0.5em,"j?"'] &
H_{\bullet}(Y) \\
& H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\oplus H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,shift right=0.5em,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"']
  \arrow[ur,bend right,"f_*\oplus g_*"']
\end{tikzcd}
```

But each time I compile it gave me a compilation error and some of the errors are:

1- An error for this part $ \arrow[r,"c_*"]$ is the following error :Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '" c_*\par ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

2- An error for this part $ \arrow[dr,bend right,"\Delta"']$ is the following error: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color "\Delta \T_1 \textquotedblleft'."

3-  An error for this part $\arrow[r,"(f\vee g)**"]$ is the following error : Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '" (f\vee g )**\par ' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

4- An error for this part $\arrow[d,shift right=0.5em,"j?"']$ is the following error: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color "j? \T_1 \textquotedblleft'."

This is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}




\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Sprache (neue deutsche Rechtschreibung)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Mathematik
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}


\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{bbm}

\usepackage[margin= 1 in]{geometry}

%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.575in}
    %\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.275in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{- .1 in}

\title{M T}
\author{MA }
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{If we have the following} 

**Also the following code compiles but without any maps on the arrows:**

\[
  \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
  & H_{\bullet}(Y)
     & \\
  & H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"(f\vee g)_*"] 
  & \\
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[uur,out=80,in=190,"f_*"]
  \arrow[r]
  \arrow[ur,"i_{1*}"]
  &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
  \arrow[u,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"]
 &
  H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X) 
  \arrow[l]
  \arrow[uul,out=100,in=-10,"g_*"'] 
  \arrow[ul,"i_{2*}"']
  \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Any help in solving these problems will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

to document preamble since `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` change meaning of some symbols in `tikzpicture`. This is corrected/restored by adding Ti*k*Z library `babel`. Som MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
% Sprache (neue deutsche Rechtschreibung)
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
% Mathematik
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{commath}
% diagrams
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} % <-----

\usepackage[margin= 1 in]{geometry}

%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.875in}
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.575in}
    %\addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

    \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.275in}
    \addtolength{\textheight}{- .1 in}

\title{M T}
\author{MA }
\date{April 2020}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{If we have the following}

**Also the following code compiles but without any maps on the arrows:**

\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3em]
        & H_{\bullet}(Y)
            &       \\
        &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X\vee \Sigma X)
        \arrow[u,"(f\vee g)_{*}"]
                &   \\
H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
\arrow[uur,out=80,in=190,"f_*"]
\arrow[r]
\arrow[ur,"i_{1*}"]
        &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)\times H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
            \arrow[u,"i_{1*}\oplus i_{2*}"]
            &   H_{\bullet}(\Sigma X)
            \arrow[l]
            \arrow[uul,out=100,in=-10,"g_*"']
            \arrow[ul,"i_{2*}"']    \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]