# How to draw a commutative diagram with a half circle added on its left?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Here is the figure I wanna draw:

> [image]

I know how to draw the commutative diagram without the extension on the left of my figure, here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
 \usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}
 

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
M \ar[r] \ar[d, "\mathrm{Pinch}" ' ] \arrow[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3", sloped]
     &   * \ar[d] \\
M \vee M \vee M \ar[r, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}" ']
      &   N \arrow[r]
         
  & \dots
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Any help on how to add this half circle in the figure?

**EDIT:**

I have a problem in the order of putting $E$ and $B$ to get 2 bended arrows as in my picture above.

Here is my new code:

```
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
M \ar[r]  \dar[bend right]  % <--- 
\dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ]
     &   * \ar[d] 
     &   E \\
M \vee M \vee M \ar[r, "{(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)}" ']
    &   N \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

**EDIT:**

Another trial, here is my new code:

```
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
M \ar[r]  \dar[bend right] % <--- 
\dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ]
     &   * \ar[d]\\ 
     S' \dar[bend right]\\
     M \vee M \vee M \ar[r, "{(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)}" ']
    &   N \\
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your MWE does not reproduce showed image
- if you like to bend some arrow, just add to its option `bend right` or `bend left`, for example, based on your MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[sep=large]
M \ar[r] \dar["\mathrm{Pinch}" ] 
  \ar[dr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3", sloped]
  \dar[bend right]  % <--- 
     &   * \ar[d]   \\
M \vee M \vee M \ar[r, "{(\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3)}" ']
    &   N \dar      \\
    & \dots
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But if I would like to bend 2 times as in my drawing .... how should I do this?

Comment: @Happy, (i) your drawing is not clear (ii) shoed way how to draw bended arrows you can use/repeat anywhere in your diagram between any two nodes.

Comment: Sorry for the not accurate code .... I adjusted it for myself but I am keeping it the same in the question so that your answer will match what I am saying.

Comment: I need a bended arrow from A to E and then from E to B ... I always mistakes what should come after what.

Comment: I think I solved my problem ... thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @Happy, your behavior is not nice. First you accept answer, than change the mind, rewrote the question and than claim, that you solve your problem yourself. Why you ask for help in the first place? And if I consider, that so far you ask more than 25 question, all about commutative diagrams, from which already https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596572/adjusting-a-code-of-a-diagram has answer, from which you can learn, how to draw bended arrows ... I got a filling, that you not keen to learn anything rather simple wait on someone, who will do your job.

Comment: I am so sorry that you saw me like this, I did not do this intentionally, I will correct my attitude in my later posts. I am sorry I just forgot to reaccept your answer, I accepted it now. at the very beginning I thought your answer will help me, but then when I tried I got stuck, this is why I erased my acceptance. Anyway I am very sorry if my behavior was not nice, I promise I will be thorough in accepting the answers and in asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it by doubling the number of rows.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
&[-2em]
  M \arrow[r]
    \arrow[dd, "\mathrm{Pinch}"']
    \arrow[ddr, dashed, "\beta_1 + \beta_2 + \beta_3", sloped]
    \arrow[dl,bend right]
& * \arrow[dd]
\\
E \arrow[dr,bend right]
\\
& M \vee M \vee M \arrow[r, "{(\beta_1 , \beta_2 , \beta_3)}"']
& N \arrow[r]
& \dotsb
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Note the slight reduction of the horizontal space between the first two columns.

[image]